# Makefiles for Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, nmake, msvc12

I have few queries regarding makefiles for MSVC. I want to create makefiles which will compile my project on Visual C++ compiler. One thing I found in the web named "nmake" which is said to be the makefiles for MSVC(correct me if I am wrong).

So, I introduced myself with nmake and compiled a single source file successfully with this. But the issue is, I need to run this nmake file using command prompt of visual studio. I haven't found a way to use the file in normal command prompt. Is it really possible?

Suppose, I don't have a visual studio installed. I have only the visual C++ compiler. Then how I will be able to compile my projects using nmake?

One Additional question, if I have only visual C++ compiler installed(like the old compilers eg. microsoft visual C++ 2005), then is it certain that I will get nmake command on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using only command-line tools without VS then you're probably better off using GCC. Using `nmake` and `cl` outside of VS is possible, but why make things harder for yourself? Also VC2005 is very old, you'd be missing out on C++11 support.

Comment: Actually it is a requirement. We should use Visual C++ compilers rather than GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Answering myself, so that if anyone intend to compile makefiles using nmake for Visual C++ compiler.

Yes, it is compiles in older version of visual C++ also. I have tested and it works fine. But it may cause problems when some properties are use of latest visual C++ compiler. Because you will not find those properties in older version of C++ compiler. Otherwise it is quite OK.